# Javascript - remove part of cookie with a split('|') like array

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm abit stuck.

I'm using jQuery.

I have a cookie which has the value such as :

```
1,something|2,somethingg|1,something
```

We are treating it as [0] as id and [1] as name.

I need to remove ONE where the id == '1' for example, this will leave the cookie like this:

```
1,something|2,somethingg
```

How do I go about this, it will probally be in a loop, but not sure how to remove one of them. I have this so far:

```
function removeItem(id){ 

var cookieName = 'myCookie';
 var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName);

 if(cookie){

  var cookie = cookie.split('|');




  $(cookie).each(function(index){

   var thisCookieData = this.split(',');



   if(thisCookieData[0] == id ){




   }

  });

}
```

Comment: So you're trying to get rid of duplicates? Is that the idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), like this:

```
cookie = $.grep(cookie, function(item, index){
    var parts = item.split(',');

    return parts[0] !== id;
}).join('|');
```

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.